# Make a first Electronic Address Primary

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I want to make the first electronic address that is inserted on a contact (e.g. E-mail address) a primary address, the 2nd Address may not become primary automatic when inserting the address.

Herefore I want to modify the `insert` method on the table:

```
LogisticsElectronicAddress

public void insert()
{

    ttsbegin;
    if (!this.Location)
    {
        this.Location = LogisticsLocation::create('', false).RecId;
    }

    super();
    this.updatePrimary(this.IsPrimary);

/* This is the modifications I made to check for an other primary address

    if (!this.otherPrimaryExists())
        {
         this.IsPrimary = true;   
        }

*/

    ttscommit;

    this.invalidatePresenceInfo();
}
```

The method `otherPrimaryExists()` contains:

```
   /// <summary>
/// Checks whether primary record exists for the location.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>
/// true if another electronic address record is primary for the location; otherwise, false.
/// </returns>
public boolean otherPrimaryExists()
{
    LogisticsElectronicAddress logisticsElectronicAddress;

    select firstonly RecId from logisticsElectronicAddress
        where logisticsElectronicAddress.Location == this.Location &&
            logisticsElectronicAddress.Type == this.Type &&
            logisticsElectronicAddress.IsPrimary == true &&
            logisticsElectronicAddress.RecId != this.RecId;

    return logisticsElectronicAddress.RecId != 0;
}
```

The problem is, all Electronic address are becoming primary, and when I close the form, all primary marks are removed. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're setting `isPrimary = true` after you've already performed the insert and there are no later updates being called.

Simple solution, just move your code above the super call.

```
LogisticsElectronicAddress

public void insert()
{

    ttsbegin;
    if (!this.Location)
    {
        this.Location = LogisticsLocation::create('', false).RecId;
    }

/* This is the modifications I made to check for an other primary address
// Move this here
    if (!this.otherPrimaryExists())
        {
         this.IsPrimary = true;   
        }

*/


    super();
    this.updatePrimary(this.IsPrimary);

    ttscommit;

    this.invalidatePresenceInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify `insert` method as following:

```
public void insert()
{
    ;

    ttsbegin;

    if (!this.Location)
    {
        this.Location = LogisticsLocation::create('', false).RecId;
    }

    if (!this.otherPrimaryExists())
    {
        this.IsPrimary = true;
    }

    super();

    this.updatePrimary(this.IsPrimary);

    ttscommit;

    this.invalidatePresenceInfo();
}
```

If you set the field value after calling `super`, this value will not be stored in the database.